# Display Data from text boxes in Grid Format

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Question can i display data in grid format using in javascript/jquery but without fetching data from DB only in front end.
suppose:

```
textfield1
textfield2
    add more (link)
```

When click on add more link then user entered data display like:

```
Firstname      Lastname
amit           kumar

textfield1
textfield2
    add more (link)
```

and immediately both textfield blank. Also same next step.

pls let me know.

Comment: to answer your question , yes you can

Comment: You want to display the data in a grid... without getting the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following HTML:

```
<table id="mylist">
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input name="fname">
<input name="lname">
<button>Add More</button>
```

Then have the JS:

```
$(function(){
  $('button').on('click',function(){
    var fname = $('input[name="fname"]').val();
    var lname = $('input[name="lname"]').val();
    $('#mylist').append('<tr><td>'+fname+'</td><td>'+lname+'</td></tr>');
    // CLEAR FIELDS
    $('input[name="fname"],input[name="lname"]').val(''); // No value
  });
});
```

Comment: there's some questions you should let them research at least a little and start to write it

Comment: @ScottSelby and there are some people who are obviously new to a language/concept and a simple example that takes me a minute to write up can be a big help and save them hours of frustration.

Comment: Then you would want to 'blank' those fields afterward - a simple `$('input[name="fname"]').val('')` will do that. Passing a value to the `.val()` method will work as a set (in this case, blank)

Comment: sorry when replace .val() to .val('') then it being show objectObject like somthing..

Comment: don't replace - look at the code (I've updated it). I added the line under `// CLEAR FIELDS` comment which will clear them out. `.val()` gets the value, `.val('')` clears it - two separate things.

Comment: ok,excellent guys, little more help can i get the every object value, becoz i wants to save the data in DB like as amit kumar, sumt kumar,....in comma seprated..

Comment: That's where it starts to get more tricky - you'll either need to push through each result as it's run or create a function to serialize the data: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: can i set id in this like as $('input[name="fname" id="_1"]').val();